# Make it possible to select multiple items from Career "Where do you code?"

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

The title says it. I suggest making it possible to select more than one item from the "Where do you code?" section of Career in the profile area of Stack Overflow.

Especially *Work or School* and "*Just <3 coding*" at the same time.

> for the search:
>   * work
>   * School
>   * Just <3 coding

I need this feature, because I do both: Code at work and code for fun.

Comment: In switzerland we have a thing called apprenticeship where you have school and work. I code at work and at school. (3 and 1 days a week) What do I enter here? I would love to select both, because that represents it most accurately.

Comment: This sounds like _why_, not _where_. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @Mafii For me all 3 would apply, because I also code on leisure time. So it should be possible to choose something like "all of them" and set the focus on a specific place (for the most users "work", I guess).

Comment: @chade_ all 3 apply for me aswell :)

Answer (score 9):

This would give a broader perspective to a potential employer as to what kind of developer they are getting. Every interview I've ever done, I made a point of being sure the company knew that I did stuff on the side out of my own interest. That always made an impression.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this would be a useful addition. "Just <3 coding" can be a pretty ambiguous name for "I'm not learning to code and I'm not a professional coder either", but it's certainly short and sweet, so to say. This switch is meant to provide an easy way to determine the current relation of someone with coding.

Comment: j/k: you _could_ change your username to _the14kman_. Jokes aside, the "<3 coding" option can also indicate that the user is for example loves to put time and energy into open source contributions...

Comment: @kayess I don't think that it wants to convey that meaning in this scenario. "Just", in my opinion, means "only" here (i.e. you don't learn it in an educational system, nor work with it)